# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'GraphQLScalarType | undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql

I am trying to run a graphql query where the `Id` type is scalar `Int`.

Simply writing `Int`didn't work. `Number`also didn't work. Then I tried this:

```
import { Int } from "type-graphql";

interface WhereInput {
  phoneNumber_contains?: String;
  id?: typeof Int;
}
```

but this also didn't work.

```
const where: WhereInput = {};

 if (criteria == '6') {
      if (searchItem) {
        where.id = Number(searchItem);
        loadUsers({
          variables: {
            where: { id: searchItem },
          },
        });
      }
    }
```

Now I get an error on `where.id`that

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'GraphQLScalarType | undefined'.
```

The `searchItem`is read from a text-field and is a string by default. How can I change it to an Int?

My query:

```
interface UserFilter {
  phoneNumber_contains?: String;
  id?: typeof Int;
}
export const LoadUsersQuery = gql`
  query usersList($where: UserFilter) {
    users(where: $where) {
      ...
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot find out which type the Int scalar accepts by using the `typeof` TS operator. This operator returns the type of the Scalar which is `GraphQLScalarType`. Why not simply say:

```js
interface WhereInput {
  phoneNumber_contains?: string;
  id?: number;
}
```

In the frontend you might not want to use `type-graphql`. Instead you could generate types using [graphql-code-generator](https://graphql-code-generator.com/).

Primitive types in TypeScript are written in lower case.